# Latitude and Longitude coordinates in URL

Tags: javascript, arrays, latitude-longitude

I have a list of Latitude and Longitude coordinates and I want to replace "+lat+" and "+long+" in the below URL string (displayed on a page) with the corresponding coordinates as a random selection.

How can I accomplish this in javascript?

Latitude/Longitude coordinates:

1. 42.14/72.65
2. 42.00/71.26
3. 53.21/45.27
4. 62.56/65.25

Example of URL:

> //testpage.com?latitude="+lat+"&longitude="+long+"

Example of desired output:

> //testpage.com?latitude=42.14&longitude=72.65

Comment: `Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Store your coords in an object array and then get a random position between 0 and array length.

```
var coords = [{lat:42.14,lng:72.65},{lat:42.00,lng:71.26}];

var randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * coords.length);

var url = 'http://foo.com?lat='+coords[randomPos].lat+'&lng='+coords[randomPos].lng;
```